# Chained "fire-and-forget" waiting methods

Tags: c++, c++11, methods, callback, task

I'm having a function that waits for certain amount of time before being proceed or it's successful run is dependent on other factors such as a boolean flag.

I want to chain callbacks to sequence the operations and wait for each one for successful run.

This is an example of how I want it to work:

```
int64_t m_runTime = 0;
bool clean = false;

void check() {
    if (time(nullptr) > m_runTime) {
        return; // not yet
    }

    m_runTime = time(nullptr) + 10;
    // Emit some kind of signal to .then saying that the 'check' has finished?
}

void cleanup() {
    // cleanup everything and emit signal

    if (!clean) {
        return; // not yet
    }

    [..]
    // ok, cleanup finished
}

check().then([]() {
        // check() finished, run cleanup
        cleanup();
    }).then([](){
        // cleanup() finished, output a message
        std::cout << "all task finished successfully!" << std:endl;
    });
```

Looks pretty much like a `std::future` job.

I did a little bit of research and found a [nice method](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/future/then) that (I guess) would satisfy my needs. However, it's not yet implemented. It does exist in the boost however, but I don't want to use any frameworks.

How can I implement this without `std::future::then`?

Comment: Well, writing your own minimal task queue is pretty straightforward. But for multi-threaded applications I'M definitely recommend the usage of a library. The support in the standard library is pretty rudimentary.

Comment: That being said, if you know all parts of your chain up front, there is no reason, why you shouldn't put all of them into a single function and put that on a thread.

Comment: @MikeMB "put all of them into a single function and put that on a thread" could you be more specific here? How would it work?

Comment: Sure, if you are more specific about how check is supposed to work. Currently, check doesn't return anything, so calling `.then` on it would certainly not work, even if `std::future::then` was already standardized

Comment: Thats the thing. If was able to use future's `then` method, mostly likely I would emit signals when ready.

Comment: My understanding was that you could use boost::future or std::experimental::future, but don't want to use them for dependency reasons. However, if you think those types would solve your problem, it would be helpful if you could write the example code using them so we don't have to guess what the  semantics of your code are. Currently, it is unclear to me, what your code is supposed to do and hence I can't really suggest a solution.